# LiveCharts2 - stop interpolating missing points

Tags: c#, livecharts, avaloniaui

I'm trying  to plot some financial data using a cartesian chart from (the otherwise fantastic) LiveCharts2 library in an Avlonia UI app. The finanncial data is on a daily basis but misses data for Saturdays/Sundays/Holidays of course. However LiveCharts automatically interpolates the missing points. How can I create a plot in which the neighboring points are simply connected and missing points in time are simply ignored?

This is my xaml:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart AutoUpdateEnabled="True" Series="{Binding Series}"   ZoomMode="X" XAxes="{Binding XAxes}">
```

In the ViewModel I create the XAxes as below:

```
    public ICartesianAxis[] XAxes { get; set; }   = new ICartesianAxis[]
    {          
            axis1 = new Axis 
            {
                Labeler = value => new DateTime((long) value).ToString("dd.MM.yy"),  
                LabelsRotation = 80,          
                MinStep = TimeSpan.FromDays(1).Ticks,
            },
    };
```

The values for the linechart are stored in a `ObserveableCollection<DateTimePoint>` and then added to `Series`:

```
LineSeries<DateTimePoint> newlin = new LineSeries<DateTimePoint>();
newlin.Values = line.valsAbs.Values; //line.valsAbs.Values is an ObservableCollection<DateTimePoint>
Series.Add(newlin);
```

Series itself is again an ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<ISeries> Series { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ISeries>()
```

I'm confused why I can't prevent this interpolation of data. I thought there might be a property for my `LineSeries` which can turn this off but there doesn't seem to be one. I've also removed the axes without success and also tried to replace `LineSeries<DateTimePoint>` by `LineSeries<ObservablePoint>` but even then the "missing" data is interpolated.
The other idea I would have now would be to simply use a LineSeries and then bind the XAxes values to a separate collection of dates - but I hope there is a simpler way to achieve what I'm trying to do (given that it must be an issue with almost any financial data)

Answer (score 0):

LiveCharts 2 will draw a line between all available points in the series for a Cartesian chart.  It has no way of knowing that a point is missing because it doesn't know your frequency or resolution, or even if the frequency should be consistent.

If you want it to plot a gap, you have to give it null data where the "missing" data would be.  Since you are using a DateTimePoint, one null data point anywhere in the time span of the missing data will remove both connecting lines (left and right) of that null point.

Also note that it does not like `double.NaN`, so you need to condition that out of any data.